# Additional properties in Umbraco member groups

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I am currently using Umbraco version 7.9.1 . I need to add some extra property other than name in Umbraco member groups.

I would like to know are there any packages to achieve this or can it be done from Umbraco backend programmatically.

Any kind of solution will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can definitely do this programmatically. Take a look at Nik Remington's approach for this. He has written 3 blogs about this so far, more will come as far as I know.
https://justnik.me/blog/creating-a-public-profile-page-for-members-in-umbraco-part-1

Comment: I think the question is about adding properties to member groups, and the answer is about adding properties to members.